# Blood - Bloods - pluralisation

Tags: word-usage, etymology, grammatical-number, technical, medical

Why is it that the plural of 'blood' is 'blood' in normal usage but 'bloods' (e.g. 'I'll be taking some bloods') is acceptable in a medical context? Are there any words with similar pluralisation anomalies?

This odd pluralisation *may* be confined to British English, here are some examples

- http://m.studentmidwife.net/student-midwife-forums-2/clinical-placements-and-electives-8/3845-taking-bloods.html
- "[Reasons for taking bloods](http://www.babyandbump.com/miscarriage-support/626402-reasons-taking-bloods-any-information-would-great.html)"
- "[When to have bloods tested for progesterone?](http://www.babyandbump.com/trying-to-conceive/866899-have-bloods-tested-progesterone.html)"
- http://www.mail-to.co.uk/Forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=13134
- http://www.imt.ie/opinion/2011/09/restraint-should-be-last-alternative-in-taking-bloods.html

UPDATE: I'm struggling to find online examples of this usage outside of midwifery as per the links above. Now I'm wondering if 'bloods' is actually a pluralisation that refers to both the mother and baby's blood. Has anyone an example of a medical usage outside of pregnancy?

Comment: I have never heard *"I'll be taking some bloods,"* and it sounds very strange to me. What is the context? Are they talking about taking blood from more than one person? If that's the context, it makes sense to me. Otherwise, I'd say no, it's not acceptable.

Comment: *The Bloods* — isn't that a street gang in LA or something?

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, and members of their rival gang, The Crips, might be very likely to say "I'll be taking some Bloods."

Comment: The plural of "blood" is not "blood" in normal usage. In normal usage, "blood" is a mass noun that it always grammatically singular and simply does not take a plural form at all.

Comment: The next time you visit EL&U, would you mind updating the question by adding the quotes, I tried the first link and got a ‘page not found’ message.

Comment: 'bloods' is medical speak for 'blood samples'

Answer (score 18):

"Bloods" is not a plural of "blood", but rather, the shortening of "blood test", often among medical professionals. Thus, that explains why "bloods" is acceptable in a medical context.

Answer (score 8):

There is no plural *blood* – it is an uncountable noun.

*Blood* in medical context probably is a slang term for *blood sample* or *blood test*, as @Thursagen points out, which makes it countable and subject to normal pluralization rules.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you have been but the term *bloods* is used on a daily basis in hospitals and doctors surgeries. It is totally wrong to use *bloods* when referring to one person as they only have one blood. But it is correct when referring to a number of people.

Answer (score 1):

The word "blood" is considered "uncountable", so grammatically it [always remains singular](https://awelu.srv.lu.se/grammar-and-words/selective-mini-grammar/noun-phrases/classes-of-nouns/).

The only time I'm aware of the word "bloods" being usable is in reference to the [LA street gang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloods). In that case it makes sense because a "Blood" is a member of the gang, and people *are* countable.

So if someone says, "I'll be taking some bloods", the only way I know to interpret that is that they are bringing along some gang members with them.

Comment: @sumelic - I believe the technical term today is "uncountable" (when I was a kid they called them "quantity nouns"). See https://awelu.srv.lu.se/grammar-and-words/selective-mini-grammar/noun-phrases/classes-of-nouns/

Comment: @sumelic - Well, as you can probably tell from my comment, that isn't the term I was taught, and I didn't feel like parroting today's fashionable jargon for that kind of word would necessarily be particularly enlightening compared to a description of what the jargon means.  You're clearly right that the description was inadequate though (based on the score here). I'll see if I can't do something...

Answer (score 0):

They might be using bloods in the meaning of blood containers. I am not sure but since you heard it in medical context then that could be.

Comment: please refer to my updated question. it may be confined to brit-english and obstetrics.

Comment: Actually it's 'blood samples'